# Socket - host invalid syntax? python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-3.x, syntax

Right, so I am making a simple communicator between two programs on ONE machine, although I am planning to put the program on two machines and make them communicate on the local LAN. I am getting an invalid syntax at the host on the client.py

-Server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                
s.bind((host, port))        

s.listen(5)                 
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send("Thank you for connecting".encode())
   c.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = 192.168.1.161  
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

I am using Python 3.x

Comment: In addition to not quoting the `host` string, you are not actually *calling* the `s.close` method. `s.close()` would be a call.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why I was confused is why do you have to not put the port number in quotes?

Comment: Because it is an int literal; it is a straight natural number. IP addresses on the other hand are not a literal value in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should quote the host string:

```
host = "192.168.1.161"
```